Как получать время работы в бизнес-аккаунте Telegram?
В тг ввели бизнес-аккаунты и одна из особенностей, это возможность указать "время работы".
Я не смог найти способ получить это время в боте на aiogram. Если выводить на печать информацию о пользователе, чате или вообще все данные приходящие, то там есть параметр business_opening_hours, но он приходит None.
Есть ли вообще возможность получить время работы указанное в профиле в боте?

может часы работы не указаны в аккаунте?

Указаны, видимо aiogram не полностью поддерживает последнюю версию апи. Если сделать запрос вручную, параметр показывает часы работы, а если обращаться к тому же методу в aiogram, то там None.
Ответ подсказали тут: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78468374/how-to-get-opening-hours-in-a-telegram-business-account-via-bot
